# What's the big O of an algorithm that does n-m operations, where m is the iteration number?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've wrote an algorithm that looks for duplicates in unsorted lists. It does n - m operations on each iteration where m is iteration number and n is size of input list. What is its big O?

Comment: initial values are n and and n - 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O(n^2). The work here is `n+(n-1)+(n-2)+...+1 = n(n+1)/2`.

A more intuitive way to look at it is that you do at least `n/2` work for at least `n/2` iterations, so you do at least `n^2/4` work.

Comment: but from what i understand `n(n+1)/2 < n^2`. or am i missing something?

Comment: Big-O doesn't care about constants, just about the highest order term. Your function does about half the work it would need to if it did `n` work each iteration, but that's still `O(n^2)`

Comment: @Daniel The fact that `n(n+1)/2 < n^2` is exactly why it's `O(n)`.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I think you meant *O(n^2)*, not *O(n)*.

Answer (score 4):

```
  (n - m) + (n - m - 1) + (n - m - 2) + ... + (n - m - m)
= (n * m) + m + (m - 1) + (m - 2) .. - (m - m)     # Group the `n`s
= (n * m) + (1 + 2 + .. + m)                       # Carefully reverse this sum
= (n * m) + 0.5 * m * (m + 1)                      # sum(1...n) = n(n+1)/2
```

`m` should range from `0` to `n`, so:

```
= (n * n) + 0.5 * n * n + 0.5 * n                  # Just substitute `n` for `m`
= 3/2 * n^2 + 0.5 * n                              # Combine the `n^2` terms
-> 3/2 * n^2                                       # n^2 >> n for large enough n
=> n^2                                             # Drop the constant
```

I'm probably doing this a bit too verbosely.